Cómo llamar imágenes que se incluyen en un plugin?
aquí una consulta: tengo un plugin con imágenes y con la siguiente estructura
nombre_plugin
|--class
       |--mensajero.php (donde está mi clase mensajero que llama a imagen)
|--public
       |--images/logo.png

lo que quiero es mostrar dicha imagen en el frontend.
intenté con este codigo
private function mostrar_imagen($imagen) {
            
            
            // Obtener la URL base del plugin
            
            $plugin_url = plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ );
            // Ruta de la imagen dentro del directorio del plugin
            $imagen_url = $plugin_url . 'public/images/'.$imagen;
            return $imagen_url;
        }

Técnicamente me devuelve la dirección correcta a la imagen, pero no logro hacer que aparezca en el frontend.
Es más, intenté llamar a la imagen directamente desde la barra de direcciones del navegador, pero me devuelve a la pagina principal.
Debe de existir alguna instrucción, pero no logro dar con ella.
Gracias de antemano por su apoyo.

plugin_dir_url() y plugins_url() la segunda es para usar en init o admin_init pues es filtrable ( podes cambiar el resultado via hooks )

al parecer estas teniendo una redirección, para debugear proba desactivar todos los plugins excepto el tuyo y usar un theme classic. también podes usar el plugin "query monitor" para revisar el stack. desde panel o via cli wp plugin install query-monitor && wp plugin activate query-monitor

intenta en el front con:
<?php

echo '<img src="'. mostrar_imagen($imagen).'" />';

?>

De todas formas intenta no complicar el código con una función para mostrar imagenes, la idea es mantener todo de la manera mas sencilla posible, llama la imagen directamente.

Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas en el centro de ayuda.

Hola, bienvenido a [ES.so], por favor lee [answer]
